# Beginner to R using table of counts to create table of proportions

Tags: r, proportions

```
penguins.table = table

penguins.table( penguins$species, penguins$island )
```

this created my table of counts.

Next task for to create a table of proportions

```
penguins.prop= prop.table
penguins.prop = prop.table( penguins.table, 2)
```

or I've tried this

```
penguins.prop (penguins.table, 2)
```

I receive this in R:

```
Error in marginSums( x, margin) : 'x' is not an array
```

I'm learning basic r code, but is there something wrong with my code as to why it's not working in particular?

I need to be able to produce a stacked bar plot with the data, however, am stuck trying to achieve this.

Comment: Hey Kate! If you can, please provide a reproducible example of your data so people can look at it. You can do this by using the `dput` command on your dataset, then copying and pasting what it spits out from R.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I'm very new to this so unsure on what dput command is?

Comment: No prob! Here is a link that briefly describes how to share it:
https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Use the command `dput(head(penguins, 15))` and then copy/paste the output into your question.

Comment: structure(list(species = c("Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", 
"Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie"), 
    island = c("Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", 
    "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe"), sex = c("male", 
    "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", 
    "male", "male"), body_mass_g = c(3750, 3800, 3250, 3450, 
    3650, 3625, 4675, 3200, 3800, 4400)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1):

From your first two pieces of code, I'm assuming that you wanted to make a `prop.table` using `species` and `island`. The code below will do that. You can add more variables you're interested in on the `select(` line next to `species` and `island` (or you could just do the whole dataframe with `df`, but it will be a lot).

```
df <- structure(list(species = c("Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie"), 
island = c("Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe"), 
sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male"), 
body_mass_g = c(3750, 3800, 3250, 3450, 3650, 3625, 4675, 3200, 3800, 4400)), row.names = c(NA, -10L ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

library(tidyverse)
smalldf <- df %>% select(species, island)
prop.table(x = table(smalldf), margin = 2)
#>         island
#> species  Biscoe
#>   Adelie      1
#prop.table(x = table(df), margin = 2) 
# ^ a lot of output
```

Answer (score 0):

## For proportion of nominal data:

Here is an alternative that just uses base R commands. This way only requires one string of code after you've loaded your data:

```
#### Load data ####    

penguins <- structure(list(species = c("Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie", "Adelie"), 
                         island = c("Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe", "Biscoe"), 
                         sex = c("male", "female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "male"), 
                         body_mass_g = c(3750, 3800, 3250, 3450, 3650, 3625, 4675, 3200, 3800, 4400)), row.names = c(NA, -10L ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 
    

#### Make proportion table ####
    
prop.table(table(penguins$species,
          penguins$island))
```

Which gives you the same output as the tidyverse method:

```
         Biscoe
  Adelie      1
```

## For proportion of numeric data:

If for some reason I am not understanding your query, here is what you can get for proportions if you mean the numeric variable here, body mass, and the only grouping variable of interest, sex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
gt(penguins)

penguins %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarize(Proportion_Mass = body_mass_g/sum(body_mass_g))
```

This gives you this proportion of mass table:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   sex [2]
   sex    Proportion_Mass
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 female           0.219
 2 female           0.188
 3 female           0.199
 4 female           0.209
 5 female           0.185
 6 male             0.185
 7 male             0.180
 8 male             0.231
 9 male             0.187
10 male             0.217
```